# Una variable que guarda un Objeto puede acceder a los metodos de la Clase del tipo de objeto?

Tags: php

Me explico, si guardo un objeto dentro de una variable normal puedo ocupar la variable para entrar a los metodos como si fuera un objeto nuevo??

Por ejemplo:

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=prueba_datos', 'root', '');
```

Aqui creo el objeto `$conexion`

```
$statement = $conexion->Prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = :id');
$statement->execute(array(':id' => 5)); 

$resultado = $statement->fetch();
```

Y el objeto de tipo `PDO` lo guardo dentro de una variable normal, despues esa misma variable puede acceder a metodos PDO como si fuera un objeto de esa Clase, sin instanciar ningun objeto por ejemplo:  `$statement = new PDO();`

entonces mi pregunta es que si una variable que guarda un objeto puede comportarte como un objeto de la misma Clase???

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tu haces la instancia de una clase sobre una variable, la variable, tiene accceso a los metodos y propiedades.

Ejemplo:

```
Class Car{
  public function run(){
    echo 'runing';
  }
}

// puedes hacer

$myCar = Car();

$myCar->run();
```

Ahora, algo muy importante, es posible que el método `run` (de este ejemplo), pueda retornar la misma clase, para hacer útiles otros métodos.

```
Class Car{

  private $running = false

  public function run(){
    echo 'runing';
    $this->running = true;    

    // Ojo aqui
    return $this;
  }

  public function isRunning(){
    return $this->running;
  }

}
```

Con esta clase podemos tener varias alternativas para lograr el mismo resultado.

Ejemplo 2.1:

```
$myCar = new Car();

echo $myCar->isRunning(); // retorna: false

$myCarRun = $myCar->run(); // retorna: Car::class

echo $myCarRun->isRunning(); // retorna: true
```

Ejemplo 2.2

```
$myCar = new Car();

echo $myCar->run()->isRunning(); // retorna: true
```

Ejemplo: 3

```
class Count{

    private $total = 0;

    public function add(){
        $this->total ++;
        return $this;
    }

    public function total(){
        return $this->total;
    }
}

$count = new Count();

$myCount = $count->add()->add()->add()->add()->add();
$myCount = $myCount->add();

echo $myCount->total();
```

En este ejemplo, tenemos una clase que tiene el metodo `add` y retorna su misma clase permitiéndose utilizar más métodos o los mismos métodos de si misma para poder lograr el objetivo deseado.

En tu caso es posible que `$conexion->prepare()`, este retornandose a si misma, dandole cabida a poder utilizar el metodo execute, por lo que puedes hacer `$conexion->prepare()->execute()`, sin nececidad de guardar el resultado del metodo `prepare` en otra variable.

Answer (score 0):

Considera que al hacer esto:

```
$objeto = new Clase();
```

Estas indicando que `$objeto` esta siendo una *instancia* de dicha clase, la cual podrá:

- Acceder a los métodos y propiedades de dicha clase, con la sintaxis de:

Código:

$objeto->propiedad/metodo();

Ahora en esta línea en específico:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = :id');
```

Estas indicando:

- que la variable `$statment` almacenará el resultado de *preparar* dicha consulta, que según PHP y cito<sup>1</sup>

> PDO::prepare — Prepara una sentencia para su ejecución y devuelve un objeto sentencia

- El objeto `$conexion` contiene en si misma al *acceso* a los métodos y propiedades de la clase `PDO` por lo cual se hace innecesario que hagas esto: `$statment = new PDO` ya que estarías duplicando en intención la existencia de `$conexion` ya que en este punto: *estarían disponibles 2 instancias accediendo a la misma clase con todo lo que esta contiene*.

Ahora por ejemplo si imprimes el proceso de preparado de la consulta con ayuda del método `debugDumpParams()` obtendrás un resultado como el siguiente que se almacena en la variable `$statment`:

```
> php app.php
SQL: [34] SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id
Sent SQL: [34] SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1'
Params:  1
Key: Name: [3] :id
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":id"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

**¿Qué ocurre si no hago uso del objeto `$conexion`?**

Considera que:

Si ejecutas esta línea:

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
```

Sin el acceso al objeto que es instancia o representación de dicha clase, de este modo:

```
$consulta = prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
```

Vas a obtener un resultado como este:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function prepare() in

**¿Por qué obtengo este error?**

Precisamente por lo que te mencionaba mas arriba

- Los métodos tales como: `fetch`, `prepare()`, `execute()` y demás solo existen dentro del contexto de la clase `PDO`
- Con base en el punto anterior, entonces comprendemos que PHP desconoce de dicho método pues no tiene *forma de accederlo* ya que la representación o instancia de la clase no existe en la estructura de la consulta que se pretende *preparar*

**¿Qué es entonces `$resultado`?**

Si ejecutas un `gettype()` a dicha variable verás que obtiene un resultado como este:

> array

Pues te esta almacenando como resultado los valores de todas las columnas que se obtuvieron de procesar dicha consulta a tu BD.

Si imprimes con `var_dump();` a la variable resultado compruebas que la estructura corresponde al tipo de dato anteriormente mencionado:

```
array(12) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "User One"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "User One"
  ["email"]=>
  string(19) "mail@example.net"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "mail@example.net"
  ["password"]=>
  string(6) "secret"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "secret"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2019-11-18 01:24:21"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "2019-11-18 01:24:21"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2019-11-18 01:24:21"
  [5]=>
  string(19) "2019-11-18 01:24:21"
}
```

Entonces `$conexion` si es un *objeto* que *representa* a la clase `PDO` para que puedas trabajar auxiliándote de su estructura y contenido

Comment: Yo vengo de estudiar Java y siento que PHP es mucho mas permisivo que Java. Para finalizar de entender me podrías dar un ejemplo de esto mismo en Java o en Java esto no se puede hacer??

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses dame unos minutos y checo